# Finding $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^{1/6}}{(\log_2x)^4}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I try to find the limit between 2 functions (see graph below).

By deviding and take limit i get to:

How do you solve limits of the sense:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^a}{\log_2x}, a\in R
$$

Deviding the functions, i get to: (the red divided by the green)

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^{1/6}}{\log_2^4x}
$$

I tried:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^{1/6}}{\log_2^4x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{x^{1/24}}{\log_2x}\right)^4
$$

So i need to solve the limit: 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^{1/24}}{\log_2x}
$$

I tried L'Hopital:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{1/24}}{\log_2x} = 1/24 \cdot \ln2\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{x^{23/24}} = \infty
$$

But as i look at the graph, it seems that this limit should be $0$ and not $\infty$
Can you give a hint?

[image: The graphs of the functions, from desmosgraph]

Thank you.

Comment: Why does the graph suggest the limit is $0$?

Comment: It seems that the green one is much bigger than the red and just getting bigger as we proceed to infinity, isnt it?

Comment: Anyway deviding the red by the green, absolutely doesnt seem as infinity in the limit, as the red is smaller than the green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^{1/6}}{(\log_2x)^4}.$ As you said, it is true that as $x$ approaches $\infty,$ $f(x)$ tends to $\infty.$

However, when $x$ is small, $f(x)$ does become quite small. For example, when $x=2^{10},$ $f(x)=\frac{2^{10/6}}{10^4}=0.0006...$ Even when $x=100,$ $f(x)=0.001...$ The red graph only ever over-takes the green graph when $f(x)>1,$ which happens when $x$ is about $1.2957157\cdot 10^{54}$.

When $x$ is large enough, however, as the limit suggests, $f(x)$ does also become quite large. When $x=2^{1000},$ $f(x)=\frac{2^{1000/6}}{1000^4}=1.48\cdot 10^{38}.$

Comment: OK thanks, so the graph just confused me.